# My testcases are not passing. I don't know what the issue is. Since i Cannot see the testcase i'm having difficulties

Tags: python, statistics

I was asked to write a program for Linear Regression with the following steps.

Load the R data set mtcars as a pandas dataframe.
Build another linear regression model by considering the log of independent variable wt, and log of dependent variable mpg.
Fit the model with data, and display the R-squared value

i tried the following 2 models and the tests are not passing. Is there an issue with my code.

#case 1

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars')
mtcars_data = mtcars.data
liner_model = sm.formula.ols('np.log(wt) ~ np.log(mpg)',mtcars_data)
liner_result = liner_model.fit()
print(liner_result.rsquared)
```

#case 2

```
import statsmodels.api as sa
import statsmodels.formula.api as sfa
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


mtcars = sa.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars')
cars_data = mtcars.data

lin_mod2 = pd.DataFrame(cars_data)
lin_mod2['wt'] = np.log(lin_mod2['wt'])
lin_mod2['mpg'] = np.log(lin_mod2['mpg'])

lin_mod1 =  sfa.ols("wt~mpg",lin_mod2)
print(lin_mod1.fit().rsquared)
```

#or

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf


mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars','datasets',cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
model = smf.ols(formula='np.log(wt) ~ np.log(mpg)', data=df).fit()
r = model.rsquared
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it passed. the question was wrong I think all i had to do was print.

```
model.summary()
```

not

```
model.rsquared
```